# Trouble handling list index error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The script I have written to parse name, address and phone number from yellowpage is working perfectly as long as I'm excluding phone number from print statement.
If I try to print the three of them, it throws error showing "list index out of range". I can't find out the remedy myself. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url=requests.get("https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&page=1")
soup=BeautifulSoup(url.text,'lxml')
for item in soup.findAll(class_="info"):
    name=item.findAll(class_="business-name")[0].text
    address=item.findAll(class_="adr")[0].text
    # phone=item.findAll(class_="phones")[0].text
    # print(name,phone,address)
    print(name,address)
```

Link for sir adam: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/pt9yk6y5zu9r0ag/For%20sir%20adam.txt?dl=0"

Comment: Are you sure there is a class with the name of "phones"?

Comment: Yep, sure.  I have checked it.

Comment: Does this `work phone=item.findAll(class_="phones").text`?

Comment: For your information, if you make the page number 2 and run the scraper, you will find no error. It is throwing error cause some items in that page are missing and i can't handle them.

Comment: Can you set up a `try/except` block?

Comment: Thanks Matt Cremeens, for your answer. Yep I tried that try/except block. It did the job but it's not a workaround rather it bypasses the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting `name`, `phone` and `address` it's better to use `find` which returns only the first match instead of `findAll` which returns a list of all matches.

As for your question, the first item in `soup.findAll(class_="info")` has no 'phones' tag and so `item.findAll` returns an empty list, which gives you an error when you try to select the first item.

You can handle this case either with a try - except or  if - else block. Examlple :

```
for item in soup.findAll(class_="info"):
    name=item.find(class_="business-name").text
    address=item.find(class_="adr").text
    phone=item.find(class_="phones").text if item.find(class_="phones") else None
    print(name,phone,address)
```

Or if you insist on using `findAll` :

```
phone=item.findAll(class_="phones")[0].text if item.findAll(class_="phones") else None
```

Using a function :

```
def if_exist(item, item_class):
    pro=item.find(class_=item_class)
    if pro:
        return pro.text
    return ""
```

Example :

```
phone=if_exist(item, "phones")
```

Comment: Thanks sir t.m.adam for your answer. Your provided solution always rocks. Anyways, I just wanted to apply here a user defined function that i can only create if the script is written using xpath but in this case I can't do that. I have updated my post with a link for you to watch What I'm after. Thanks again sir. Btw, the reason I'm looking for the user defined function is because when there are more than 10 categories to parse then writing each field this way is tedious.

Comment: So you're looking for a function similar to `if_exist` for the items in the loop, yes? Let me update my post.

Comment: Perfect, awesome, mindblowing and expression can be given like these. Thankssssssssssss a lot sir.

Comment: Thank you so much, don't make me blush!

Comment: Sir t.m.adam, please take a look into the link in your spare time "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224058/class-crawler-written-in-python-throws-attribute-error" .I'm very new in writing classes so can't understand how to run it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url=requests.get("https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&page=1")
soup=BeautifulSoup(url.text,'lxml')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in soup.findAll(class_="info"):
        name=item.findAll(class_="business-name")[0].text
        address = item.findAll(class_="adr")[0].text if len(item.findAll(class_="adr")) else 'No Address' 
        phone = item.findAll(class_="phones")[0].text if len(item.findAll(class_="phones")) else 'No Phones'
        print(name,phone,address)
```