# Class crawler written in python throws attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, web-scraping

After writing some code in python, I've got stuck in deep trouble. I'm a newbie in writing code following the OOP design in python. The xpaths I've used in my code are flawless. I'm getting lost when it comes to run the "passing_links" method in my "info_grabber" class through the instance of "page_crawler" class. Every time I run my code I get an error "'page_crawler' object has no attribute 'passing_links'". Perhaps the way I've written my class-crawler is not how it should be. However, as I've spent few hours on it so I suppose I might get any suggestion as to which lines I should rectify to make it work. Thanks in advance for taking a look into it:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

class page_crawler(object):

    main_link = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA"
    base_link = "https://www.yellowpages.com"

    def __init__(self):

        self.links = [self.main_link]


    def crawler(self):
        for link in self.links:
            self.get_link(link)

    def get_link(self, link):

        print("Running page "+ link)
        page = requests.get(link)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        item_links = tree.xpath('//h2[@class="n"]/a[@class="business-name"][not(@itemprop="name")]/@href')
        for item_link in item_links:
            return self.base_link + item_link

        links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]//li/a/@href')
        for url in links:
            if not self.base_link + url in self.links:
                self.links += [self.base_link + url]



class Info_grabber(page_crawler):

    def __init__(self, plinks):
        page_crawler.__init__(self)
        self.plinks = [plinks]

    def passing_links(self):
        for nlink in self.plinks:
            print(nlink)
            self.crawling_deep(nlink)

    def crawling_deep(self, uurl):

        page = requests.get(uurl)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

        name = tree.findtext('.//div[@class="sales-info"]/h1')
        phone = tree.findtext('.//p[@class="phone"]')
        try:
            email = tree.xpath('//div[@class="business-card-footer"]/a[@class="email-business"]/@href')[0]
        except IndexError:
            email=""

        print(name, phone, email)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    crawl = Info_grabber(page_crawler)
    crawl.crawler()
    crawl.passing_links()
```

Now upon execution I get a new error "raise MissingSchema(error)" when it hits the line "self.crawling_deep(nlink)"

Comment: If you haven't already - take a look at [scrapy](https://scrapy.org) - it'll save you reinventing the wheel as it were.

Comment: Thanks sir Jon Clements, for your comment. I have worked with scrapy as well. I wanted to know the basic patterns of class and different aspects. Thanks again.

Comment: I think you meant to initiate the `Info_grabber` instance with a string ( a url ) , while instead you're passing a `page_crawler` object in `plinks`, which crashes your program when you try to 'fetch' it with `requests` in the `crawling_deep` method. Easy fix: `crawl = Info_grabber('http://some.url')` . It won't crash your program, but i doubt it will give you the expected results. I realize that you're trying to improve your OOP skills with this project, but i think you're overcomplicating things.

Comment: Thanks sir t.m.adam for caring to answer. I gave an url to Info_grabber class and it does fetch expected results for a single link. However, with my page_crawler class I noticed that it was able to produce 400 links which I wanted to pass to the Info_grabber class but can't find any idea. Here is a single link among those 400 newly produced links to see the result. crawl = Info_grabber('https://www.yellowpages.com/san-francisco-ca/mip/bravo-pizza-1352298?lid=1000928926028') It is necessary to comment out parse.crawler().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand what you're trying to do in `page_crawler.get_link`, but i think you should have a different method for collecting "pagination" links.
I renamed `Info_grabber.plinks` to `Info_grabber.links` so that the `page_crawler.crawler` can access them, and managed to extract info from several pages, however the code is far from ideal.

```
class page_crawler(object):

    main_link = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA"
    base_link = "https://www.yellowpages.com"

    def __init__(self):
        self.links = []
        self.pages = []

    def crawler(self):
        for link in self.links:
            self.get_link(link)

    def get_link(self, link):
        print("Running page "+ link)
        page = requests.get(link)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        item_links = tree.xpath('//h2[@class="n"]/a[@class="business-name"][not(@itemprop="name")]/@href')
        for item_link in item_links:
            if not self.base_link + item_link in self.links:
                self.links += [self.base_link + item_link]

    def get_pages(self, link):
        page = requests.get(link)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]//li/a/@href')
        for url in links:
            if not self.base_link + url in self.pages:
                self.pages += [self.base_link + url]


class Info_grabber(page_crawler):

    def __init__(self, plinks):
        page_crawler.__init__(self)
        self.links += [plinks]

    def passing_links(self):
        for nlink in self.links:
            print(nlink)
            self.crawling_deep(nlink)

    def crawling_deep(self, uurl):
        page = requests.get(uurl)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        name = tree.findtext('.//div[@class="sales-info"]/h1')
        phone = tree.findtext('.//p[@class="phone"]')
        try:
            email = tree.xpath('//div[@class="business-card-footer"]/a[@class="email-business"]/@href')[0]
        except IndexError:
            email=""
        print(name, phone, email)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = page_crawler.main_link
    crawl = Info_grabber(url)
    crawl.crawler()
    crawl.passing_links()
```

You'll notice that i added a `pages` property and a `get_pages` method in `page_crawler`, i'll leave the implementation part to you.
You might need to add more methods to `page_crawler` later on, as they could be of use if you develop more child classes. Finally consider looking into composition as it is also a strong OOP feature.

Comment: I'm on a mobile device so can't check it. Your solution always rocks. I will give you the feedback as soon as I'm around my pc. Btw, your answer never needs to be tested to accept. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I tested your code and found results the way I expected. It seems you could read my mind again. The bottom line is I wanted my Info_grabber class to make use of those links generated by page_crawler by building a bridge between the two and you showed me how. Thanks a trillion once again sir t.m.adam.

Answer (score 1):

Your `crawl` is an instance of the page crawler class, but not the InfoGrabber class, which is the class that has the method `passing_links`. I think what you want to do is make crawl an instance of InfoGrabber instead.

Then I believe before doing self.crawling_deep you must do:

```
if n_link:
    page = requests.get(n_link).text            
    tel = re.findall(r'\d{10}', page)[0] if re.findall(r'\d{10}', page) else ""
    print(tel)
```

Comment: Thanks Cary Shindell, for your answer. After changing what you suggested when I run again I get a new error "raise MissingSchema(error)" when it hits   the line "self.crawling_deep(nlink)" in my "info_grabber" class. Thanks.